# Let $V$ and $W$ be real representations of a torus $T$ s.t. $\dim V^H=\dim W^H$, $\forall H<T$. Show that $V\simeq W$

Tags: representation-theory, abelian-groups

$V^H:=\{v\in V:hv=v,\,\forall h\in H\}$ is the fixed point set.

I'm trying to show this result first for the irreducible real representations, which are the trivial (one dimensional) ones and those given by

$$x=[x_1,\cdots,x_n]\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos2\pi\langle a,x\rangle & \sin 2\pi\langle a,x\rangle \\ -\sin\pi\langle a,x\rangle & \cos2\pi\langle a,x\rangle  \end{array}\right);$$
with $a\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\langle a,x\rangle=\sum_ja_jx_j$.

Also, every subgroup of $T$ is compact and abelian, thus its irreducible real representations are either one-dimensional and of real type or two dimensional  and of complex type.

I'm also trying to approach it via decompositions in weight spaces, but I'm kinda stuck.